# Hide executable symbols from nm command

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nm

The **nm** command lists all symbols in executable. this is good guidance for reverse engineering and crackers. I want to hide them. The **gcc** maybe has switches for this purpose but *I do not use gcc*. Is there an approach to hide them directy from binary file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [strip](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_strip.htm) command.

But I won't bother that much removing symbols. Very probably, your program might not interest a lot of people (as most programs). And if there is a security issue, it could eventually be found (e.g. by using `strace` to understand the behavior) even on stripped binaries.

Answer (score 1):

`strip` will "strip" (remove) symbols from a binary.